# defaulted default constructor ? in n3290 draft

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, default-constructor

A point from n3290 draft §12.1 (Constructors) ¶5:

> An implicitly-declared default constructor is an `inline public` member of 
>   its class. A **defaulted default constructor** for class `X` is defined as deleted
>   if:
>
> - `X` is a union-like class that has a variant member with a non-trivial 
>     default constructor,
> - any non-static data member with no brace-or-equal-initializer is of 
>     reference type,
> - any non-variant non-static data member of const-qualified type (or array 
>     thereof) with no brace-or-equal-initializer does not have a user-provided 
>     default constructor,
> - `X` is a union and all of its variant members are of const-qualified type
>     (or array thereof),
> - `X` is a non-union class and all members of any anonymous union member are of
>     const-qualified type (or array thereof),
> - any direct or virtual base class, or non-static data member with no 
>     brace-or-equal-initializer, has class type `M` (or array thereof) and either 
>     `M` has no default constructor or overload resolution (13.3) as applied
>     to `M`’s default constructor results in an ambiguity or in a function that is 
>     deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted default constructor, or
> - any direct or virtual base class or non-static data member has a type with a
>     destructor that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted default constructor

Please explain the **defaulted default constructor** with some example program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think **[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Explicitly-defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions)** excerpt from Wikipedia explains this:

**Explicitly-defaulted and deleted special member functions**

> In C++03, the compiler provides, for classes that do not provide for themselves, a default constructor, a copy constructor, a copy assignment operator (operator=), and a destructor. The programmer can override these defaults by defining custom versions. C++ also defines several global operators (such as operator= and operator new) that work on all classes, which the programmer can override.
>
> However, there is very little control over the creation of these defaults. Making a class inherently non-copyable, for example, requires declaring a private copy constructor and copy assignment operator and not defining them. Attempting to use these functions is a violation of the one definition rule. While a diagnostic message is not required,[5] this typically results in a linker error.[citation needed]
>
> In the case of the default constructor, the compiler will not generate a default constructor if a class is defined with any constructors. This is useful in many cases, but it is also useful to be able to have both specialized constructors and the compiler-generated default.
>
> C++11 will allow the explicit defaulting and deleting of these special member functions. For example, the following type explicitly declares that it is using the default constructor:

Code Example:

```
struct SomeType 
{
    SomeType() = default; //The default constructor is explicitly stated.
    SomeType(OtherType value);
};
```

---

Since you seem to be a Standerdese fan(Almost all of your Questions seek explanations on Standard Quotes) this paper here about how standards committe arrive to defining default and deleted functions should be a good read for you:

**[Defaulted and Deleted Functions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2210.html#explicit)**

Answer (score 0):

One of the special member functions is "defaulted" if it is declared with the `= default;` syntax. The line right before the first line you quoted states:

> If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4).

Therefore, a "defaulted" default constructor is a default constructor (constructor that can be called with no arguments) that is declared with `= default`. This can be explicitly defined using the `= default` syntax, or implicitly defined, per the above line.